# Default to miniconda rather than conda

Tags: conda, miniconda

If one has both conda and miniconda installed, is there a way to force the `conda` command to default to the miniconda installer from the mac terminal? I can't seem to find this anywhere on the internet. If not, how does one use the miniconda installer at all? I seem unable to use it over the already-installed conda installer.

-PolyyloP

Comment: Depends on the `PATH` environment variable. The first path that contains `conda` executable will be used. Put miniconda's path earlier in this environment variable

Comment: I changed the path, and that did not fix it. When I type `which conda`, I get
```
conda () {
 \local cmd="${1-__missing__}"
 case "$cmd" in
  (activate | deactivate) __conda_activate "$@" ;;
  (install | update | upgrade | remove | uninstall) __conda_exe "$@" || \return
   __conda_reactivate ;;
  (*) __conda_exe "$@" ;;
 esac
}
```
and when I type `whereis conda`, I get nothing

Comment: The term usage here appears confused. "Conda" is the software that manages virtual environments and software packages; Anaconda, Miniconda, Miniforge are various distributions of Conda. Perhaps OP really means "Anaconda" everywhere "Conda" is written?

Comment: Either way, one only ever needs a single distribution of Conda.